# Basics on how to setup horizontal paging in iOS app?

Tags: ios

I've looked for this for a while, but I can't find any good guides or resources that explain it thoroughly (not even Apple's own documentation, which seems to not have as much information as I'd expect). I want to setup a basic interface that has 6 pages horizontally. Each page will have a bunch of labels and textboxes, but the layout will be the same for each page. Eventually, I want to be able to have each page scroll down to view all the content, but I'm assuming I just need to use scrollviews as the content for each page.
Also, each page will eventually have to have separate names for each textbox (and separate from the other pages too) because I'll need all the content of the whole app to be saved out later.

But really, for now, I just need to figure out how to get paging working. I tried following one demo but when I typed in the code, Xcode wasn't recognizing one of my classes (which I know I included it). Plus, I didn't understand what was going on really, and I feel that I need to understand what I'm coding.

Also as a side note, how do I start programming for iOS 5? I updated Xcode to the latest version which said it had support for iOS 5, but I only get up to 4.3 in my project target.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for UIPageControl.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this project http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/icarousel, the only downside is it does not support cell reuse, so if you plan on having more than a 5 or so panels the app will really start to blog down.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for something even simpler. All I want are pages like how the iOS homescreen works, but I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: iCarousel will do that, it has configurable options, and will save you having to build your own using UIScrollView.

Comment: I downloaded it and ran the example, but it didn't have what I'm looking for. I kind of have an idea of how to setup paging (just enable paging on the scrollview) but I don't really know exactly how. Does anyone know of any guides that would explain it (other than Apple's official documentation)? I've googled but there aren't any good ones that I could find.

Comment: Check out the sample app included with this library: https://github.com/nicklockwood/CustomPageControl - it includes a working paged scrollview implementation.

Answer (score 0):

For any future searchers that have found this thread, I was able to achieve what I wanted.
Basically, just make a scrollview the size of however many pages you want (multiply the width by how many pages you want and that will be the content width). Then just enable paging in interface builder and it will page through the view. Then you can just add content to the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard. When I did it for some of my apps, I had a very detailed 'template view' which included primarily a tableview, but also lots of buttons and text fields and such. I was amazed at how well it all worked when put together -- no real trouble with gestures or anything. [Apple's UIPageControl sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html) is a good place to start.